# Workflow - How to convert string to number to date?

Tags: workflow, date-time, conversion

I have a string strExpDate and I get the value "`130836384000000000`" from ldap query. The active directory field is `accountExpires`. I need to convert this to date/time. The result should be `8/9/2015 7:00:00 PM`. I tried convert this string to number but the formatting of the `1E+30`. I can't use this number value to calculate date. I wanted to use this formula `(strExpDate/(8.64*10^11))-109205` but not sure which action I need to use. Any suggestions?

The following formula in excel gives `8/9/2015 7:00:00 PM`

```
(130836384000000000/(8.64*10^11))-109205
```

Comment: Why not use this in a calculated column and then use it in workflow?

Comment: Not allowed to create calculated column per company SP governance.

Comment: What about an event receiver or workflow to bind that value to another column on item change?

Comment: "Not allowed to create calculated column per company SP governance."  LOL, +1 for the best line in years. Are you allowed to call an API from a Workflow? Are you allowed to set a Column in an Item with a Workflow?

Comment: Mike: I am trying to use the workflow to update the list column. however, I dont know how to convert the string date into date/time using SharePoint OOTB workflow. Any ideas?